# How to Handle Changing IDs In XPath? for example :

Tags: python, selenium

//*[@id="bede971c-0687-4699-9e9b-f10f375b6a62"]
id: bede971c-0687-4699-9e9b-f10f375b6a62 keeps on changing when reloading the page
Is there any way to handle this type of situation in Selenium?

Comment: Just don't use `@id` as locator

Comment: Page will be dynamic so you need to use class instead of id